# Maximizing linear objective function with absolute values

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control, linear-programming

This has be asked on other forums, though couldn't
find authoritative answer.

I have a linear program over the reals and don't
want to introduce integer or binary variables.

The objective function is $\text{maximize} \sum |x_i|$
(maximizing sum of absolute values of variables).

> Is is possible to model this as a standard linear
>   program (without integer variables and extensions like
>   disjunctions).

What I know.  Minimizing sum of absolute values
is possible.

[This blog](http://orinanobworld.blogspot.fr/2012/07/modeling-absolute-values.html) suggests several solutions.  The solution with SOS2 method
appears to work sometimes in glpk and coin-or, though sometimes it
doesn't work.

The `lpsolve` documentation suggests using a binary variable.

If this is impossible, there might be reduction from
a NP-hard problem.

Comment: What do the constraints look like? If you have a typical polyhedral feasible region, then maximizing the sum of absolute values is in general nonconvex, hence not a linear program (which are convex).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general such a problem is NP-hard, so not expressible by a polynomially-sized linear program.  A special case of the problem you mention is computing the $\lVert A\rVert_{\infty,1}$ norm of a matrix, i.e. the maximum of $\lVert Ax\rVert_1$ over all $x$ with $\lVert x\rVert_\infty\leq 1$.  Rohn has shown that this matrix norm is NP-hard to approximate in the paper [``Computing the norm $\Vert A\rVert_{\infty,1}$ is NP-hard''](http://uivtx.cs.cas.cz/~rohn/publist/norm.pdf).